# How can I create a table of sliders?

Tags: list-manipulation, gui-construction

I'm trying to do the following:

I have a table:

```
w = Table[ToExpression[ToString[h] <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, Length[c]}]
```

This table is suposed to generate variables, like the following list:

```
{h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7, h8, h9, h10, h11}
```

I'm trying to create a table of vertical sliders with this by adding this to the code:

```
w = Table[VerticalSlider[Dynamic[ToExpression[ToString[h] <> ToString[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[c]}]
```

It create a it gives me an error:

```
Set::write: "Tag ToExpression in \!\(ToExpression[\"hi\"]\) is Protected.
```

I'm aware that this may not be the best way todo this but it's all I can imagine, I guess the other feasible way would be with loops, I don't know. Can you help me?

Comment: Your code doesn't work as it is because  `c` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16893/5

Comment: @gpap It is defined in the code, but I copied only what is relevant to the question.

Comment: I'm sure @gpap knew that. He was probably just pointing out that you posted a non working snippet. Which is easily fixed, but you might have taken the time to do that your self.

Comment: Yes, @ajasja is right: I just thought that it's better to have working code for people to copy-paste and experiment with. I think you should edit it  appropriately either replacing `Length[c]` with whatever length `c` has in your original code or give `c` (not the case here, but it **could** have been that `c` was too long and that caused your problem - a working snippet would help exclude such cases).

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `Dynamic` is preventing `ToExpression` from evaluating to a symbol.  When you drag the slider it's trying to evaluate:

```
ToExpression[ToString[h] <> ToString[1] = 0.1
```

and you get a message about not being able to set the value of `ToExpression`.

I would use `With` to create the symbols and insert them into the `Dynamic`:

```
w = Table[With[{var = ToExpression[ToString[h] <> ToString[i]]}, 
       VerticalSlider[Dynamic[var]]], {i, 1, Length[c]}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you're going to do next, this might be useful:

```
 x = {.1, .2, .3, .4, .5};
 Outer[Slider[Dynamic[x[[#1]]], {0, 1}] &, Range[Length[x]]]
```

This creates a collection of sliders, one for each element of x. The values of x provide the initialization, and when you move a slider, the corresponding element of x changes. You can see this happening in real time using

```
 Dynamic[x]
```

Comment: +1 Btw `Slider[Dynamic[x[[#1]]], {0, 1}] & /@ Range@Length@x` is another option (I'm just not used to seeing `Outer` instead of `Map` ;)

Comment: You're right... I might have written it in functional form Map[Slider[Dynamic[x[[#1]]], {0, 1}] &, Range[Length[x]]] rather than postfix form, but Map[ ] is probably clearer than Outer[ ].